# Pandas: sum DataFrame column for max value only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have the following DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.28, 0, 0.25, 0.85, 0.1],
                   'b': [0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.75, 0.1],
                   'c': [0.33, 0.7, 0.25, 0.2, 0.5],
                   'd': [0, 0.25, 0.2, 0.66, 0.1]})
```

Output:

```py
      a     b     c     d
0  0.28  0.50  0.33  0.00
1  0.00  0.50  0.70  0.25
2  0.25  0.00  0.25  0.20
3  0.85  0.75  0.20  0.66
4  0.10  0.10  0.50  0.10
```

For each column, I want to sum the top `n` max values of the column, where `n` is determined by how many *row max* values that column contains.

For example, column `b` has a row max only in row 1, so its sum is the sum of the top 1 max values in that column, which is just `0.5` -- but column `c` has three row-maxes, located in rows 1, 2, and 4, so the top 3 max values of column `c` should be summed.

Expected output:

```py
          a     b     c     d
0      0.28  0.50  0.33  0.00
1      0.00  0.50  0.70  0.25
2      0.25  0.00  0.25  0.20
3      0.85  0.75  0.20  0.66
4      0.10  0.10  0.50  0.10
count  1.10  0.50  1.45  0.00
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic. Can you please explain all four values in the `count` row?

Comment: Why does your second dataframe not match your first?

Comment: @ddejohn second dataframe is expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`where`

```
df.append(
    df.where(                # only look at values that are max for the row
        df.eq(               # compare max values to all values in row just
                             #     in case there are more than 1
            df.max(axis=1),  # actually get max values
            axis=0
        )
    ).sum().rename('count')
)

          a     b     c     d
0      0.28  0.50  0.33  0.00
1      0.00  0.50  0.70  0.25
2      0.25  0.00  0.25  0.20
3      0.85  0.75  0.20  0.66
4      0.10  0.10  0.50  0.10
count  1.10  0.50  1.45  0.00
```

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to do this would be to using the .max() method passing through the axis argument:

```
df.max(axis =1)
```

If you're after another column:

```
df['column_name'] = df.max(axis =1)
```

I didn't read the question that well!

Comment: thank you but this is not what I want.